# Black screen on android app after taking a picture but it works when connected to a debugger

Tags: android, camera, imageview, photo

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now and cannot seem to get past it. Basically I have an activity that has 3 image views with a button that starts the camera intent

The problem is that while I am developing and running through the debugger, everything works perfectly but not when I run the app alone (no debugger, just on the phone) after accepting the picture preview it just shows a black screen and does nothing after that.

All that is needed is for the picture to display in the image views and save to the gallery, it does all of this while in debug mode but not when I need to run the app independently.

I am completely at a loss with this problem - please can someone / anyone assist me.

I think this may be an async issue but I am very new to android and dont know how to implement this, in my head and through the tutorials I have read / watched - this should be an easy process, however I cannot seem to get it to work

Here is my code on the layout for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PhotoActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPhoto1"
        android:layout_width="236dp"
        android:layout_height="136dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dds_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPhoto2"
        android:layout_width="236dp"
        android:layout_height="136dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgPhoto1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dds_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPhoto3"
        android:layout_width="236dp"
        android:layout_height="136dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgPhoto2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dds_logo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTakePhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgPhoto3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the code for the onClick event:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            //respond to clicks
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnTakePhoto) {
                captureImage();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the call to the intent:

```
private void captureImage() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);

    }
```

Here is the onActivtyResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try{

            if (!Debug.isDebuggerConnected()){
                Debug.waitForDebugger();
                Log.d("debug", "started"); // Insert a breakpoint at this line!!
            }
            if(numPhotos < 2) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

                String savedImageURL = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(),
                        imageBitmap,
                        "Serial",
                        "Refresh Verification photo"
                );

                switch (numPhotos) {
                    case 0:
                        imgPhoto1.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        imgPhoto2.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        imgPhoto3.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                        break;
                }
                numPhotos++;
            }
            else
            {
                numPhotos = 0;
                Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, "Max # of ohotos reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Day All,

I managed to solve the issue, it occurs because the quality of the image captured by the camera is too high.

After compressing the image, everything works fine (both preview and saving), the only thing I needed to change was the OnActivityResult method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

try {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    final Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bytes);
    byte[] byteArray = bytes.toByteArray();
    final Bitmap compressedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

    if (numPhotos < 3) {

        switch (numPhotos) {
            case 0:
                imgPhoto1.setImageBitmap(compressedBitmap);
                savebitmap(compressedBitmap);
                numPhotos++;
                break;
            case 1:
                imgPhoto2.setImageBitmap(compressedBitmap);
                savebitmap(compressedBitmap);
                numPhotos++;
                break;
            case 2:
                imgPhoto3.setImageBitmap(compressedBitmap);
                savebitmap(compressedBitmap);
                numPhotos = 0;
                Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, "Max # of ohotos reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                break;

        }
    } else {
        numPhotos = 0;
        Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, "Max # of ohotos reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();;
}
```

}

Here is the savebitmap method:

```
public static File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) throws IOException {

        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/RefreshPhotos");

        boolean var = false;
        if (!folder.exists())
            var = folder.mkdir();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        File f = new File(folder
                + File.separator + "RefreshPhoto_" + date + ".png");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
        return f;
    }
```